# How to serve robots.txt with Perl Dancer

Tags: perl, web, seo, web-crawler, dancer

I am trying to serve a robots.txt using the Perl Dancer web framework. I thought having a route that just returned the text would work, but it seems to be wrapping it in `html` and `body` tags. I'm assuming this won't be interpreted properly as a robots.txt file by crawlers.

Any idea how to do this properly?

Here is how I have the route written:

`get '/robots.txt' => sub {
    return "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /";
};`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What makes you think it's being wrapped in HTML and BODY elements?

```
use Dancer;

get '/robots.txt' => sub {
   return "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n";
};

dance;
```

Output:

```
>lwp-request -e http://127.0.0.1:3000/robots.txt
200 OK
Server: Perl Dancer 1.3112
Content-Length: 26
Content-Type: text/html
Client-Date: Mon, 29 Apr 2013 05:05:32 GMT
Client-Peer: 127.0.0.1:3000
Client-Response-Num: 1
X-Powered-By: Perl Dancer 1.3112

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

I bet you're vieweing it with a client that uses a renderer that adds those on seeing the Content-Type header of `text/html`. Setting the content type to `text/plain` would be more appropriate and look better in the renderer you are using to view the file.

```
get '/robots.txt' => sub {
   content_type 'text/plain';
   return "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n";
};
```

Ultimately, though, it shouldn't have any effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 6):

The other option for sending `robots.txt` would be to *not* define a route for it and instead put an actual `robots.txt` file into the `public/` subdirectory under your main Dancer app directory.  Dancer will then serve it automatically as a regular file without passing it through the route handlers, templates, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You are serving the response as `text/html` (the default). The elements are being inserted by the browser as part of the normal process of parsing HTML (and you are looking at a representation of the live DOM rather than the source code).

Set the correct [content-type](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer#content_type) header.

```
get '/robots.txt' => sub {
  content_type "text/plain";
  return "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /";
};
```